# How to add a fixed width of td table

Tags: css

I set a fixed width in td, but it doesn't work when the table is overflow. What I have tried is the below code.

```
td {
       width: 192px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can resolve by following 2 steps.

1 - On table set width:100%

2 - On td of table use class like this when your data get overflow.

```
.dataRow
{           
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;           
}
```

3 - after above 2, you can also set width as per your requirement, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can change in css with `td { width:20px}` or you can change it inline `<td style="width:20px">.`

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieve using `display` property.

Check below Snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-scroll tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.table-data {
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
}

.table-detail {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}

td.first {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <table class="table-scroll table-data">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="first">HEAD1</td>
        <td>HEAD2</td>
        <td>HEAD3</td>
        <td>HEAD4</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```